# Centering bulleted list with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have list inside section. I want to center the list so that bullets are vertical lined. How do I do that with flexbox?

Removing `flex-direction: column` and `text-align:center` is not an answer, since I need them in other content of the page.

```css
.text-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align:center;
}

ul{
  list-style-type:disc;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-list">
<ul>
<li>short</li>
<li>and very long line</li>
<li>shorter line</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Comment: use margin:auto in ul that will do

Comment: Nope. Maybe I should look for different solution to this if direct flexbox using is not good in this kind of situation.

Comment: Not only margin auto in ul work. You also need to text-align: left; and justify-content: left in .text-list class. If I understand your question correctly. I update my answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Thanks @Akash Pandey ul margin: auto suggestion 
Can you try this [example](https://codepen.io/husain100b/pen/YBLPZK) also see below

```
.text-list{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: left;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align:left;
 }

ul{
  list-style-type:disc;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! would +1 If I had enough reputation. My final setting to this was to get other content centerized. I'm not really sure how this works, but text-align:left and margin: auto; seems to do it.    <pre> .text-list{
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align:left;
 }

ul{
  list-style-type:disc;
  margin: auto;
} </pre>

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, Just add this css to your ul

> ul { display:table; margin:0 auto;}

```css
    ul {
      display:table;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .text-list {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align:center;
    }    
    ul {
      list-style-type:disc;
    }
```

```html
<section class="text-list">
  <ul>
    <li>short</li>
    <li>and very long line</li>
    <li>shorter line</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try centering the `text-list` using `display:flex;` and `align-items: center;` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
.text-list{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

ul{
    min-width:auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    flex-direction:column;
}



<section class="text-list">
    <ul>
        <li>short</li>
        <li>and very long line</li>
        <li>shorter line</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```